# From representations of $SL(2)$ to representations of $SL(2)^\pm$

Tags: representation-theory

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108122/representations-of-sl2-r-and-psl2-r) is an analogue but not exactly what I want. The irreducible unitary representations of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ are given by

- discrete series $D_m^\pm$ for $m \geq 2$
- limits of discrete series $D_1^\pm$
- principal series $P_{\varepsilon, i\nu}$ where $\varepsilon \in \{0, 1\}$ and $\nu \in \mathbb{R}$
- complementary series $C_u$ for $u \in (0, 1)$

I would like to understand what is the analogue classification for $SL(2, \mathbb{R})^\pm$ (matrices of determinant $\pm 1$), in which $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ is on index 2. Ther is one non-trivial element in the quotient, so that some representations should glue up together I suppose. But which ones?